# bpf map gone after call bpf_map_update & bpf_map_lookup when high-pps environment (fast access)

Tags: xdp-bpf

I have some problem while processing packets via eBPF/XDP.

I do update rule via bpf_map_update_elem function on userland

and XDP_Kern program use lookup to get rule and process packets.

but when High-PPS Environment, userland have failed to update bpf map and also XDP_Kern failed to lookup bpf map.

then bpf map never come back before restart program.

What is the problem between lookup & update?

Is there any solution for solve this?

like lockless function or exchange map without mutex.

Try to search out __sync_compare_and_swap and other solutions like other platforms. ex) InterlockedExchange.

also tried spinlock. but not working for me, when compile and run.. bpf program return error.

Comment: We are going to need some more information, what is the error you get when doing map calls at high PPS? For the map problem, maps are only removed when no references to it exist anymore, so as long as a userspace or kernel program is using it it will say, use pins if you would like it to persist beyond that. A small reproducer for the issues you are having would help a lot. Additionally, if you are encountering verifier errors, you should provide those as well.

Comment: Also, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry for my article, I tried to print errno after fail, errno return 2. but this is so weird. working codes have problem when only high-pps.

Comment: I have problem while running program, when I does not touch bpf map on userland. nothing has problem, but as I said, I use rule for firewall. so need to update bpf map. it happen randomly. so I just though it is problem like deadlock.

Answer (score -1):

Seems problem has been solved.

I called bpf_map_lookip helper function on userspace without any sleep.

Just looped like below:

```
void loop_update() {    
  for(;;){    
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){    
      bpf_map_update_elem(map, key, dat, BPF_ANY);    
    }    
    sleep(1);    
  }    
}
```

now I added
`usleep(1000*10);` under `bpf_map_update_elem(map, key, dat, BPF_ANY);`

```
void loop_update() {    
  for(;;){    
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){    
      bpf_map_update_elem(map, key, dat, BPF_ANY);    
      usleep(1000*10);    
    }    
    sleep(1);    
  }    
}
```

seems problem has been solved. Thank you.